# gradle: avoid same custom task in multiple project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have following folder structure...

```
project/ 
project/library 
project/app1 
project/app2
```

Now I have build one custom task `publish` (copy my android apks to a server folder). This task is in `/app1/build.gradle` **and** `/app2/build.gradle`.

My task is in both app same, except I have set `project.ext` variables. How can I put this task in `/build.gradle`(in root), because I don't want to change every single build.gradle in every app. The problem is, that `/library` should not have this task.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html) document section: *14.3. Configuring the project using an external build script*

**UPDATE**

Structure

- p1

  - build.gradle - empty file
- p2

  - build.gradle
- build.gradle - empty file
- settings.gradle
- custom.gradle

  *custom.gradle:*

  **task hello << {
    println "hello!"
    println project.sample_prop
  }**

  *settings.gradle:*

  **include 'p1', 'p2'**

  *p2/build.gradle*

  **apply from: '../custom.gradle'**

  **project.ext.sample_prop = '1'**

Comment: It seems not to work. I set `apply from: '../own.gradle'` and set the `project.ext` variables into my app1.


I received following message: `cannot get property 'publishDir' on extra properties extension as it does not exist`

Comment: Edited to answer to provide full example. Is that what are You looking for?